# Filter large csv files (10GB+) based on column value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter

**EDITED : Added Complexity**

I have a large csv file, and I want to filter out rows based on the column values. For example consider the following CSV file format:

```
Col1,Col2,Nation,State,Col4...
a1,b1,Germany,state1,d1...
a2,b2,Germany,state2,d2...
a3,b3,USA,AL,d3...
a3,b3,USA,AL,d4...
a3,b3,USA,AK,d5...
a3,b3,USA,AK,d6...
```

I want to filter all rows with `Nation == 'USA'`, and then based on each of the 50 state. What's the most efficient way of doing this? I'm using Python. Thanks

Also, is R better than Python for such tasks?

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem but instead of looking for only one filter, I may have to look for multiple e.g. in the countries column, what if I want to filter for USA, Japan, and Canada? I want to store the output in another CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Nation'] == "Japan"]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.query('Nation == "Japan"')
```

Second should be faster, see [performance of query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#performance-of-query).

If still not possible (not a lot of RAM) try use [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) as commented Jon Clements (thank you).

Comment: If the machine can handle a 10gb file loaded to filter... yeah... otherwise a straight-loop and check, or maybe looking at a `dask.dataframe`...

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to filter the csv first and then load, given the size of the data

```
import csv
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    with open('yourfile_edit.csv', 'w') as f_outfile:
        f_out = csv.writer(f_outfile, escapechar=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

        for line in f_in:
            line = line.strip()
            row = []
            if 'Japan' in line:
                row.append(line)
                f_out.writerow(row)
```

Now load the csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile_edit.csv', sep = ',',header = None)
```

You get

```
    0   1   2   3       4
0   2   a3  b3  Japan   d3
```

Comment: I am new to python, but am looking for a similar answer. I am wondering why is this solution adding empty rows after each record?

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file, index the position of the `Nation` header, then iterate over a `reader()`.

```
import csv

temp = r'C:\path\to\file'

with open(temp, 'r', newline='') as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # next(cr) gets the header row (row[0])
    i = next(cr).index('Nation')
    # list comprehension through remaining cr iterables
    filtered = [row for row in cr if row[i] == 'Japan']
```